# When exactly did Vinay Varma's and Sameera's phones get swapped in Vikram Vasudevan's narration?

Tags: plot-explanation, evaru

In [*Evaru*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaru) (2019), Vikram Vasudevan denies Sameera's words and reveals that Sameera tossed Vinay Varma. Thereafter, Sameera and Ashok use ropes to get down to the location where Vinay Varma fell. Sameera hears noises and asks Ashok to go back. Afterwards, Sameera finds Vinay Varma to be missing.

When exactly did Vinay Varma's and Sameera's phones get swapped in this Vikram Vasudevan's narration?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have watched the movie completely. There are different narratives in this film. One from Sameera and other what actually happened.

After Vinay Varma falls down due to Ashok's push, Ashok and Sameera both go down using a rope ladder. Sameera takes her phone out from her back pocket to call ambulance. But Ashok stops her from calling.

> Sameera :Thank God he's alive. We have to call an ambulance.
>
> *Ashok pushes phone in her hand*
>
> Sameera : (*Yells*) What the hell Ashok!
>
> Ashok : Are you crazy? If we take him to the hospital, we will go to jail.

Nonetheless, Sameera searches for her phone but picks up similar looking Vinay Varma's phone to call the ambulance. At **1:08:10** two phones are shown in the frame. Because she was tensed, she picks up Vinay Varma's phone.

> It's later revealed in the climax it was the other way around. It's Sameera who pushed Vinay Varma.

Comment: Your answer fits only for Sameera's POV not from Vikram Vasudevan POV. I am asking about Vikram Vasudevan POV i.e what actually happened. I edited my question **to the point**